# Asset pipeline precompile issue when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have built a Rails 4 and I am now trying to deploy to Heroku.

When I run the `git push heroku master` command, the process shuts down when Heroku runs `rake assests:precompile`. I get the following error message:

`Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "... "bootstrap" */": expected "{", was ""`

I am at a loss of where to find this error in my code. I have included the `bootstrap-sass` gem in my gem file, but I have also included the entire css folder from the download provided by Bootstrap in my assets/stylesheets folder.

Below is what I have required in my application.css.sass file:

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

As a final note, I have also precompiled locally using the `rake assets:precompile` command. In addition, I have set `config.assets.compile` equal to `true` in my application.rb file, as well as uncommenting `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass`.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*/` from your code (right below `*= require_self`). That is what the error is referring to (though it isn't very clear).

Comment: I removed that from my code, however I am still getting the same error message. I even tried removing practically all of my CSS/JS files, particularly the ones that were from Bootstrap, and I still got the same error.

Comment: Hmmm. Also try removing the `;` after the `@import` statements. Those shouldn't be there as well.

Comment: Ryan thanks for the help; turns out, I was pushing to heroku incorrectly: i was working on a feature branch and pushing to heroku master, which apparently is not possible. I switched to the proper syntax for pushing up and all worked out well.